# Reversing long read from file?

Tags: c++, long-integer, ifstream, endianness

I'm trying to read a long (signed, 4 bytes) from a binary file in C++.
My main concerns are: portability (longs are different sizes on different platforms), when you read from binary files w/ std::ifstream, it reverses the byte order (to my machine's endianness).

I understand for data types like unsigned int, you can simply use bitwise operators and shift and AND each byte to reverse the byte order after being read from a file.

I'm just not sure what I'd do for this:
Currently my code will give a nonsense value:

```
long value;
in.seekg(0x3c);
in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(long));
```

I'm not sure how I can achieve portability (I read something about unions and char*) and also reverse the signed long it reads in.

Thanks.

Comment: You would only reverse it if it doesn't match the endianness on your system.  You should use datatypes with specific sizes defined in `<cstdint>`.  Read into a string, and then construct the value using bit shifts and masking.  Then your code will be independent of the endianness on your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `long`,  use `int32_t` from `<stdint.h>` to directly specify a 32-bit integer. (or `uint32_t` for unsigned).

Use [htonl and ntohl](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl) as appropriate to get to/from network byte order.

Better:

```
int32_t value;
in.seekg(0x3c);
in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
value = ntohl(value); // convert from big endian to native endian
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use functions like htonl, htnons, ntohl and ntohs. These are used in network programming to achieve just the same goal: portability and independence of endianness.

Answer (score 0):

Since cross platform support is important to you I'd recommend using [cstdint](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) to specify the size of your types. You'll be able to say `int32_t x` (for example) and know you are getting 32 bits of data.

Regarding the endianness of the data I'd recommend standardizing on a format (eg all data is written in little endian format) and wrapping your I/O operations in a class and using it to read/write the data. Then use a `#define` to decide how to read the data:

```
#ifdef BIG_ENDIAN
  // Read the data that is in little endian format and convert

#else
  // We're in little endian mode so no need to convert data
#endif
```

Alternatively you could look at using something like [Google Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial) that will take care of all the encoding issues for you.